# universal usb installer syslinux error

Tags: live-usb, syslinux

i want to make a bootable usb with kubuntu 18.04 on it but every time i try this pop-up shows: "An error(1) occurred while executing syslinux. Your USB drive won’t be bootable."

Comment: @George Udosen : The page you recommend requires Linux for every answer. The OP is using syslinux, a Windows thing.

Comment: @karel: The same for the page you recommend.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron My link is relevant for Windows too, not just for Linux.

Comment: @roadkillorca: I have heard some installers are having problems with 18.04. UNetbootin Linux version for instance. **unetbootin-windows-661** is working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Boot Drive Programs

There are lots of options for making an installer USB in Windows, most are syslinux based..

**Some offer Live installs, (without persistence):**

[image: Rufus]

**Rufus** - 3.1.1320 (BIOS and UEFI)

[image: Copy/Paste ISO Contents]

**Copy/Paste ISO Contents** - (UEFI only)

**Some offer a choice of either Live or Persistent installs:**

[image: MultiBootUSB]

**MultiBootUSB** - 9.2.0  (BIOS and UEFI, 4GB persistence, Problems: Missing casper-rw file)

[image: Linux Live]

**Linux Live** - 2.9.4  (BIOS and UEFI, >4GB persistence BIOS only, comes with Portable Virtualbox)

[image]

**UNetbootin** - 661 (BIOS and UEFI, 4GB persistence)

[image]

**Universal** - 1.9.8.3 (BIOS and UEFI, 4GB persistence)(>4GB BIOS/NTFS)

[image: YUMI]

**YUMI** - 2.0.5.7 (BIOS only, >4GB persistence NTFS)

**YUMI-UEFI** - 0.0.0.8 (UEFI only, 4GB persistence)

All of the commercial Syslinux installers require at least three inputs:

- Location of source ISO.
- Target drive letter.
- Amount of persistence.

Several of the programs will allow formatting the drives FAT32 or NTFS, if not sure choose Default, (FAT32). NTFS does not boot with UEFI.